# Passing a specific index of an ArrayList<String[]> but String is actually a String[][]

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, reference, pass-by-reference

Sorry if this isn't explained well or isn't the proper way to go about this problem but I'm new to coding and this is my 1st question here, so go easy. Anyways I'm trying to make a trivia game where my code reads the questions and answers from separate text files and saves each of them to their own ArrayList. Each question is saved to a specific index of the type `ArrayList<String>`. Now for my answers I saved every questions' specific answers to separate 2D string arrays (`String[1][4]`) to later be transferred to the answers own `ArrayList<String[]>`. This way both ArrayList's are made to have their indexes match (question with their answers). I wanted to create my own shuffle method that way the ArrayList's remain equivalent with matching indexes between them. Now my code was literally WORKING PERFECTLY and then out of nowhere decided that was a terrible idea! I've been trying to fix it the past few days with 0 luck. My problem lies in my attempt to shuffle every questions answers; that way the answer options are never in the same order. My code is below:

```java
private static void shuffle(ArrayList<String> questions,
                            ArrayList<String[]> answers) {
    int chosenIndex;
    int questionsSize = questions.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsSize - 1; i++) {
        chosenIndex = (int) (Math.random() * questionsSize);
        swap(i, chosenIndex);
        for (int j = 0; j < answers.get(i).length; j++) {
            int answerIndex = (int) (Math.random() * answers.get(i).length);
            swapAnswers(i, j, answerIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
private static void swap(int i, int j) {
    String temp = questions.get(i);
    String[] temp2 = answers.get(i);

    questions.set(i, questions.get(j));
    answers.set(i, answers.get(j));

    questions.set(j, temp);
    answers.set(j, temp2);
}
```

```java
private static void swapAnswers(int i, int j, int a) {
    for (String[] row : answers) {
        String currentColIndexCopy = row[j];
        String randomIndexToSwitch = row[a];

        row[j] = randomIndexToSwitch;
        row[a] = currentColIndexCopy;

        break;
    }
}
```

Now again my code was working 100% but I must have done something tiny because now when it gets to my for each loop in `swapAnswers()` my answers are never shuffling the correct index for my `ArrayList<String[]>` answers. I haven't been able to notice any trend. How the code WAS WORKING was that in `shuffle()` the 1st for loop shuffles both ArrayList's so their indexes correspond. Then the 2nd for loop shuffles that questions answers but once I get to `swapAnswers()` the for each loops' answers variable is inconsistent with the current questions' answers! (By that I mean in `shuffle()` i's 1st iteration shuffles all the answers but when i increments to the next question the answers variable in `swapAnswers()` may remain on the previous questions answer's) Like I said I'm still pretty new so maybe it's a syntax error somewhere but I've tried everything and just can't seem to get this thing to work again!

NOTES:These are the class variables, questions and answers are saved under

```java
public static ArrayList<String> questions;
public static ArrayList<String[]> answers;
```

They are static which means (I think) that they can be easily accessed anywhere in my class. When I invoked `shuffle()` I passed these as arguments, which I believe was unnecessary but did it to stay safe. The only thing I didn't understand when making this was, how I was originally able to pass each answers `String[][]` to `swapAnswers()` but I had it working so I didn't question it until it stopped. I just assumed it knew the current object it was working with. I've tried to make the for each loop

```java
for (String[] row : answers.get(i))
```

where i is the parameter; which came from the current i index of `shuffle()`, and answers would return a `String[][]` but got errors and wasn't quite sure why? I know what happened was tiny, like maybe made a method an instance rather than static but if you are able to catch my mistake that would be great!

P.S. From what I've learned so far, using ArrayList's seemed like a great and organized way to go about writing this program but I've read from a few questions here to never use; or at least avoid, `ArrayList<String[]>` and I'm not quite sure why? To me I believe it allowed my objects to be more mutable in many ways here but I could be wrong and if I am an explanation of why not and better options would be awesome for my understanding. Also, any other mistakes or ideas you may have seen that I might've made that could be flawed, wrong, or are just silly routes to take would be greatly appreciated! I'm self taught so anything helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to contributing as well. I noticed that your swapAnswers is written incorrectly. How it is written it will always only shuffle the first index of answers because you pass in `int i` but never use it. The correct method is below.

```java
private static void swapAnswers(int i, int j, int a) {
    String[] row = answers.get(i);
    String currentColIndexCopy = row[j];
    String randomIndexToSwitch = row[a];

    row[j] = randomIndexToSwitch;
    row[a] = currentColIndexCopy;
}
```

Rather than having two lists for questions and answers, I would suggest creating a class called Card that would hold a string question and a list answer. That will help avoid cases like this as well as help with coding quality. You can then create functions to save it to the two list format and load it from the two list format.

I also noticed a potential bug in your first function shuffle where `for (int i = 0; i < questionsSize - 1; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < questionsSize; i++)`. Your code would never shuffle the last index unless your lucky and the last index is randomly choosen to be shuffled with a preceding index.

The reason your original code: `for (String[] row : answers.get(i))` didn't work is because `answers.get(i)` returns one row (`String[] row`) not an iterable.

I'm not sure why people say to avoid using the `ArrayList<String[]>`, but it could be because of how confusing it can get as you have experienced. You should always aim to only have Objects or basic data types (String, Float, etc.) in lists.

Comment: This is actually something I tried too and found that after a few runs it seems like it works perfectly but a small logic error I noticed was that if the 1st index swaps up 1 each increment then that would mean that the corresponding answers' index would be the only one that gets shuffled. All this means is that I should make a new object list that is a copy of answers and use that one to increment and swap answers. Then return that new lists' shuffled answers to the original; if I'm correct? This adds a bit more code than what I knew originally worked which seems very odd now looking back.

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense and definitely seems like a much more organized approach thank you! Good catch and thank you for the explanation! That's what I assumed and I really can't see how it would work but from what I remember of my code that worked perfectly, I want to say that it was there(that's why I posted this question with it). Roger that and thank you again for your help and detailed explanations they really helped and finally got me working on the rest of my program!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I think your idea of creating a copy of answers could work, but it is not very pretty. If you go with the Card class approach, one way you could handle shuffling is give each class a property called order that is a float, and when you want to shuffle them just call random for each card and store it in the order variable, and then sort from lowest to highest. This will give you a random order and can also be done with answers, though it isn't necessarily pretty either.